# Checking if a node has a connected signal with "is_connected" gives errors if there are no signals connected

Tags: godot, gdscript

In my project I dynamically (through the code) create `LineEdits` with fields the user can change in a popup `WindowDialogue`. In the similar manner I connect each `LineEdit` with a signal (`text_entered`) to a function which saves the changes made.

So, I have a simple function, which manages the `WindowDialogue` closing, i.e. deletes all children:

```
for child in parent.get_children():
        if child.is_connected("text_entered", self, "_function_name"):
            child.disconnect("text_entered", self, "_function_name")
        child.queue_free()
```

As you can see I specifically make a check if a child has connections to remove before deleting the child node from the memory. As it is, the code works correctly. However, every time the check goes through the nodes (in my cases `Label`s) that do not have a signal connected, I get this error in the debugger:

```
is_connected: Nonexistent signal: text_entered.
```

That is a logical statement from the engine I cannot argue with. My question is: is there a way to make my check go through without this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code should not show any errors even if nothing is connected to the signal. Probably `parent` has some child that really doesn't have the `text_entered` signal.

You can check whether a node (or other object) has the given signal with [`has_signal`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_object.html?highlight=has_signal#class-object-method-has-signal):

```
for child in parent.get_children():
        if child.has_signal("text_entered") and child.is_connected("text_entered", self, "_function_name"):
            child.disconnect("text_entered", self, "_function_name")
        child.queue_free()
```

However, **there's usually no need**. Signals are disconnected automatically when the node is freed.

(When using `queue_free`, the node is freed at the end of the frame, not immediately, so there are edge cases where something like this *is* needed. But I don't think this is one of those cases.)

Comment: yes, the `has_signal` check solved the problem, thank you. Apparently, Godot was checking `Label` nodes with `text_entered` signal in mind (which `Label` doesn't have by default), and throwing that error. So, I first need to check if a node **has** some signal, and then check if that node is **using** that signal, to manually disconnect it.

Answer (score 0):

You could also check the type of the `Node`. For example:

```
for child in parent.get_children():
    if not child is LineEdit:
        continue

    # rest of the code
```

Or if you are like me you prefer this:

```
for child in parent.get_children():
    var line_edit := child as LineEdit
    if not is_instance_valid(line_edit):
        continue

    # rest of the code
```